# Do you gain any speed advantage by using fixed point math in javascript, and how?

Tags: javascript, performance, fixed-point

The other day I was researching about sound synthesis in c, and learnt how much it affects to change the code to use fixed point math instead of floats, as many processors (micro-controllers in particular) are faster at calculating integers than floats. I was wondering if the same concept applies to JS. I wish it would, but I intuitively expect that JS takes the numbers always as floats underneath.

However, asking simply whether we can harness the speed of integer calculation in JS maybe is not a complete question, because there are many ways a number can be calculated.

- do operations in JS get optimized in numbers stored in an arbitrary var or let, if they are integers?
- how about dataViews and arrayBuffers, for example is it faster to bit-shift left a number in an arrayBuffer (or as an arbitrary var too for that matter) than multiplying it by two?
- does it vary depending on whether we are in node-js or a browser?

Comment: *"is it faster..."*: why do you ask when you can build a test for that and just look at the results?

Comment: You should not ask multiple questions in one question though.

Comment: thanks! Because I do not have a computer science background and I fear that some nuances might cause me to get wrong answers. 
About the multiple questions, should I edit the question to be just one?

Comment: That's what I would do. The more focussed a question is, the more chances you will get a useful answer. You can always ask a new question if some other aspects remain unclear. Make it concrete, and show that you did some effort (for instance in measuring performance).

Comment: @Joaquin it's daunting, but it fairly easy and really worthwhile to get comfortable testing how long something takes to run. Benchmarks are never perfectly accurate, but more data points is a good thing and once your curiosity is satisfied, you'll feel a lot more confident about how to proceed.